# How to know the last launch time of a Python Program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, artificial-intelligence

I am creating a Voice Assistant Program using Python and I wanna add a feature to it that shows the last time when the Assistant was used. Is there any method to do that? I am using `tkinter` for my GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Often times, the obvious answer is the easiest/right one.

In this case, why not store the previous usages of the voice assistant?

It offers you a lot of benefits:

- Being able to tell the user what was recognized previously
- Allowing the user to spot previous (perhaps untowards) usage
- Machine learning opportunities (previous utterances can be used as a reference for popular commands)
- Repeat a command from the 'last x commands' list

Answer (score 1):

In high level terms, the solution sounds like this:

- on application close (maybe even on start) you should save the current timestamp (e.g. in a file), please check https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now
- then, on application start, **try** reading the previously saved timestamp.

Comment: I say "try" because you need to address the case of "first application run".